# PHP - detection of Android Captive Network Assistant

Tags: php

Is there any way to detect Android Captive Network Assistant via PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is no way to determine Captive Network Assistant portal via PHP, the only way to do that through Javascript: [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)  can detect if Local Storage available, because in CNA portal its not.

```
if (!Modernizr.localstorage) {
       //not supported
  }
```